# does ng2+ generally use a config file with a standard name?

Tags: angular

I come from a .NET/C# background where Web.config (or App.config) is the standard name with a standard file structure used to store configuration values for an app. Does ng2+ have a similar pattern?  For example, should special configuration values generally be stored in a js file named app.config.js file?  Is there any particular expected structure or is any js object suitable for the app generally considered a good quality implementation?

Comment: There no specific name standard

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take a look at the [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). If you generate a new Angular-project via `ng new <name>`, you get a structure for your project containing the file *.angular-cli-json*. This file holds e.g. the configuration of your app (see also the *package.json*):

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "client"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Furthermore you can create components, services and other stuff with the CLI, see [Generating Components, Directives, Pipes and Services](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services). A couple of conventions are used there, take also a look at the [Angular CLI Config Schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli).